# Preact from Webpack externals

Tags: webpack, preact

## Problem

- I need to replace the webpack externals of *react* with *preact* but only on production.
- I need a way to verify that my package is using preact not react.

#### For example, on my page I would have these scripts

- `<script src="./externals.js"></script>`
- `<script src="./title-component.js"></script>`

### In my npm react component package

- My npm package, written in react, should work with my preact external script.

```
class Title extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <h1>Test</h1>
  }
}
```

### In Webpack prod config

- As per the preact documentation, I added the aliases

```
resolve: {
    alias: {    
        "react": "preact/compat",
        "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
        "react-dom": "preact/compat"
    };
}
```

### In Webpack externals

- As recommended in module bundling my build does not contain React but rather lists it as a peer dependency.

```
      react: {
            root: ['React'],
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: ['ReactDom'],
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        },
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: > I need to replace the webpack externals of react with preact but only on production.

IMHO You should always demo & test as close to production as possible.  Using `react` to iterate then `preact` for final packaging is asking for trouble since there are a few things in Preact that you can't do in React & vise versa.

Maybe a better question would be, "How to test builds using both React & Preact?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a way to verify that my package is using preact not react

Look at the compiled & un-minified code to see how the components' functions are called:

**React**: `_jsxs()` or `React.createElement()`

**Preact**: `Preact.h()` ( or maybe just `h()`? )

ref: [@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx)